# Error: Test Connection Failed for MC_Ten. Failed to Connect to the End Point : Reason Unknown

Tags: salesforce, informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-powerexchange

I'm trying to create a connection "Salesforce Marketing Cloud (Cloud Computing)" in Informatica Cloud as shown in the picture
But it gives me the error in question

[image: Error: Test Connection Failed for MC_Ten. Failed to Connect to the End Point : Reason Unknown.]

File fuelsdk-test.properties I entered:

```
endpoint= https : // www . exacttargetapis . com
authEndpoint= https : // auth . exacttargetapis . com
soapEndpoint= https : // webservice . s7 . exacttarget . com / Service . asmx

username=********
password=*********

clientId=*************************
clientSecret=**********************
```

Can you tell me how to fix the error?

Below some log (tomcat.log) if can be useful for any response:

```
2015-11-30 22:17:43,936 ERROR [com.informatica.saas.toolkit.metadataRead.resources.PluginsResource] - Exception Thrown in Operation: connect
com.informatica.cloud.api.adapter.connection.ConnectionFailedException: Failed to Connect to the End Point : Reason Unknown
    at com.informatica.saas.toolkit.metadataRead.Dao.PluginDao.connect(PluginDao.java:248)
    at com.informatica.saas.toolkit.metadataRead.resources.PluginsResource.connect(PluginsResource.java:234)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor349.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
```

Comment: Have you tried contacting Informatica support? In case of new setup they are extremly helpful. It's hard to tell what the "Reason Unknown" means.

Comment: I tried to contact Informatica Global Customer Support, but I haven't had any response
 
I would need more help about: manuals, demos, examples, eclipse project on which i can do some debug, or other ideas

Answer (score 0):

I am working for Informatica,
Error message thrown when testing the connection is either one of the connection attributes or context of the plugin fails to do connection which results the code to throw the exception error message.

"Failed to Connect to the End Point : Reason Unknown"

There is no specific information supplied in the exception to find the reason of failure.

Please post your question in informatica community for more quicker response on informatica products.

https://network.informatica.com/welcome